# MVS OS-390 - How do I Capture Job Information from CA-JOBTRAC programmatically

Tags: operating-system, rexx

I am using REXX to invoke JOBTRAC programmatically which works however I am unable to pass JOBNAME arguments using this approach. Can this be done using REXX?

The idea is to find the history of the job run using the program jobtrac. We use jobtrac's schedule to find the history of when job runs happened.  We invoke jobtrac using 
    ‘TSO JOBTRAC’ AND SUPPLY history command ‘H XXXXXX’ in the command line  (XXXXX – jobname)

I was thinking to route the jobtrac info to a flat file and parse it so that I can do some reporting real time during the job run. The above problem is also linked to this following scenario:

```
If I give dslist 'DSLIST A.B.C.*'’  in the ISPF panel
```

It gives the series of datasets ...

```
A.B.C.A,
A.B.C.D
A.B.C.E
```

When I give

```
"SAVE ORANGE"
```

it stores this list under

```
MYUSERID.ORANGE.DATASETS.
```

I know this can be automated pro grammatically and I have seen that . But I don’t have the code base to do that right now. This is much similar to the jobtrack issue I have.

Here is some REXX CODE to help with understanding. I know this code is wrong…we cannot use outtrap for this as it is used to get console output.

```
say 'No. of month end jobs considered for history :'jobnames.0


    if jobnames.0 > 0 then do
        do i = 1 to jobnames.0

        say jobnames.i
        jobname = Word(jobnames.i,1);
        say 'jobname under consideration is ' jobname;
        tsocmd="JOBTRAC;ADDLOC=000;H "|| strip(jobname);
        say 'tso command is ' tsocmd;
        y = outtrap(jobdetails.)

        Address TSO "'tsocmd'"  ------------------> wrong…I believe I have to use ispexec
        say 'job details are ' jobdetails.6;

    end;
```

Comment: If you running in TSO, it it is still a job (your user-id). How do you pass job name arguments from JCL (via a parm on the exec=parm or via a dd) ???. You can use the same methods in Rexx-TSO environment

Comment: Can you post your Rexx code (+ JCL used to run JobTrac). Currently only those people who use Jobtrac can help

Comment: i have modified my post

Comment: Unfortunately the DSLIST example is a different situation, it has a save command defined to it. From what you have provided JOBTRAC is a tso/ispf program/rexx/clist. If JOBTRAC  uses ispf panels, this approach will not work. If it accepts input from straight from the terminal, you may be about to reallocate Sysin/sysout. You really need to look at batch interface in the manuals (or talk to some one at yours site).